# Whats is the actual data size of an byte/Integer array in Java

Tags: java, networking, udp, byte

my question is a very basic one but I still struggle to fully grasp it:

My task is to send a UDP packet (Java) that contains 512 byte of random data. So that equals 4096 bit. If I send a byte array (filled with "0") with size 4096, does that equal 512 bytes ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: No, a byte array contains bytes, so a byte array with size 512 will equal 512 bytes. if you fill the array with "0", the zero will be converted to 0x00.

Comment: A byte still occupies 8 bits, even if the byte represents zero. A byte array of size 4096 is 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an interesting article here : [dzone.com](https://dzone.com/articles/java-how-to-calculate-size-of-objects-amp-arrays-b)

Here are the important parts :

> How to calculate memory usage of a Java object?: Very simplified explanation of how one could calculate a memory of any Java object. For example, lets say, you want to calculate the memory of a Java object which holds two int variables, one boolean variable, one Long object, and a reference to other objects. The memory would turn out to be following:
>
> - 8 bytes for the object header
> - 2 x 4 = 8 bytes for two int variables
> - 1 byte for a boolean variable
> - 8 bytes (object reference) + 8 bytes for long data type = 16 bytes for long object
> - 4 bytes for reference to some other object
>
> The total size of the above mentioned object will be 8 + 8 + 1 + 16 + 4 = 37 bytes + 3 bytes (for padding) = 40 bytes.
>
> How to calculate memory usage of a Java array?: The page presents examples on how to calculate size of a Java array object.
>
> For example, lets say a Java array consisting of 20 Integer objects. Following is the detail on the size:
> 12 bytes for array header object (8 bytes for header and 4 bytes for storing length of the array) ==> 20 x 16 bytes = 320 bytes for integer objects.